# Is the phrase, "having had to have walked," grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a book, and was wondering if the phrase, **"having had to have walked,"** were grammatically correct. If proper, is it too clunky? Before anyone asks, the book that I'm writing is a fantasy novel. I am aware that I am not "required" to follow all of the rules of grammar, 100% of the time.

Comment: _Having had to walk_ would be less clunky and mean the same.

Comment: There are situations where having a convoluted, clunky style is justified (read HP Lovecraft) and others where it's uncalled for (children's book). It's certainly quite clunky, but whether it's too clunky is a matter of opinion (although grammaticality is a reasonable question).

Comment: Some expressions, and I think OP's phrase is one of them, need context to form a judgement.  In isolation maybe OK maybe not, in context maybe a different view.

Comment: If you had to 'have walked' somewhere, then at some point you had to walk there.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  This could arise in story involving time travel in which a prisoner wrongly convicted for robbing a chemist shop, needs to prove that that he had to have travelled to a place miles away from the scene by bus so that he could 'find' the ticket that under the sofa in his flat.  Doesn't quite work, I admit, but I think the grammar does.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how "having had to have walked" differs from "having had to walk". The "having had" already puts the action in the past, so the "have" in "have walked" would be redundant.

The phrase "having had to have *verbed* is clunky"—I don't see any reason you should use it. Unless I'm missing something, you should just eliminate the *have*.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "having had to have walked" is grammatically correct, but it is considered clunky and awkward in terms of style and readability. In most cases, using a simpler and more straightforward construction, such as "having walked," or "having to walk," would be preferable. When writing fiction, it's important to strike a balance between artistic expression and readability. If the phrase in question adds to the story and is used in a way that is intentional and effective, it could be acceptable. However, if it detracts from the overall readability of the text, it may be better to rephrase it.

Source : Grammar.ly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"Having had to have walked" does in fact differ from "having had to walk."

For example:

> His memory had gotten so bad that he, **having had to have walked** to a place before he would be able to describe it in detail, had been diagnosed with dementia.

This means that he could only describe places that he had, at some previous time, walked to.

By contrast:

> His memory had gotten so bad that he, **having had to walk** to a place before he would be able to describe it in detail, had been diagnosed with dementia.

This means that he could only describe his own location, i.e. the place where he currently was. More precisely, he needed to walk to a place *and still be there* in order to describe it.

The latter sentence suggests his memory was far worse than the former does.

Comment: From a syntactical point of view, it is reasonable (and certainly grammatical) to reply to a statement of the form "He had to have done X" with a statement of the form "And having had to to have done X, he must also have had to have done Y" (for example). But the reply would sound much more natural if it were expressed in a form along the lines of "And having done X, he must also have done Y." At some point, the accretion of verbs in a construction may become so thick that adding yet another layer in the name of logical precision defeats immediate human comprehension.